# Google Maps Android API v2 detect long click on map and add button on it - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make a location reminder, so I need a button appear when user has detect long click, to get the information like note and sound.
I want the button to just appear at top of map fragment when user has detect long click on the map.

I'm new in Android programming.

Comment: be more specific, your question is not at all clear ! where you want button to be placed?

Comment: Do you mean marker instead of button? Long click on map to add a marker?

Comment: You mean in map fragment put a button or marker?

Comment: button , with this button i want to get some information , then if user want to save the information on that place , marker will be appear there @Amir